# Entity FrameWork Select from SQL por valores

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms, entity-framework-6

Hola amigos tengo una pregunta , estoy usando Entity Framework para consumir una base de datos SQL pero la cuestión es que quiero pedir solo ciertos valores de mi tabla, la tabla la que llamo es la tabla de usuarios que EF genera. **AspNetUsers** . Entonces, tengo este query que me llama TODO y que y lo pone en un **DataGridView**

```
 using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {
            db.AspNetUsers.Load();                
            dataGridViewPF.DataSource = db.AspNetUsers.SqlQuery
             ("Select * from AspNetUsers ")
             .ToList<AspNetUsers>();
        }
```

, la cuestión es que yo solo quiero llamar el Id, Email, UserName  y si intento algo como  `Select Id, Email, UserName from AspNetUsers` me un error diciendo que mi modelo no es apto para el query porque le faltan columas, y si cambio el modelo, no me deja hacer el query , me da un error aquí `db.AspNetUsers` diciendo que mi modelo no es comparable con mi query. Alguien sabe como puedo hacer lo que quiero?

Comment: Y si utilizas expresiones Lambda?

Comment: Disculpa , no sé a que te refieras?

Comment: [Acá](https://geekytheory.com/entendiendo-las-expresiones-lambda) tienes la explicación, en definitiva te serviria para realizar lo que requieres y en definitiva cualquier operacion que desees. Por ejemplo para tu caso seria algo como `tabla.Select(x => new { campo1 = x.campo1, ... }).ToList()`

Comment: Funcionó genial, gracias mi Inge. Si quieres la respuesta, publica y te la doy, al final hice esto `dataGridViewPF.DataSource = 
                    db.AspNetUsers.Select
                    (x => new { Id = x.Id, Email = x.Email, UserName = x.UserName }).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te mencione en los comentarios, una alternativa sería utilizar Expresiones Lambda para lo que requieres

```
dataGridViewPF.DataSource = db.AspNetUsers.Select(x => new 
                            { 
                               Id = x.Id, 
                               Email = x.Email, 
                               UserName = x.UserName  
                            }).ToList();
```

De esta forma tienes una sintaxis mucho más limpia y al mismo tiempo, aprendes a utilizar esta poderosísima funcionalidad :)

Comment: La  poderosisime!!!